# Including game levels in Cocos2d Android not taking to next scene

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-android

In Cocos2d android game i need to add levels so when the game completes it displays "You Win" after that i need to add the next level but when i try to add the following code its not replacing the scene ever. Can any one help me regarding this. Thank you in advance.

```
public void update(float dt)
{
    LinkedList<CCSprite> projectilesToDelete = new LinkedList<CCSprite>();

    for (CCSprite projectile : _projectiles)
    {
        CGRect projectileRect = CGRect.make(projectile.getPosition().x - (projectile.getContentSize().width / 2.0f),
                                            projectile.getPosition().y - (projectile.getContentSize().height / 2.0f),
                                            projectile.getContentSize().width,
                                            projectile.getContentSize().height);

        LinkedList<CCSprite> targetsToDelete = new LinkedList<CCSprite>();

        for (CCSprite target : _targets)
        {
            CGRect targetRect = CGRect.make(target.getPosition().x - (target.getContentSize().width),
                                            target.getPosition().y - (target.getContentSize().height),
                                            target.getContentSize().width,
                                            target.getContentSize().height);

            if (CGRect.intersects(projectileRect, targetRect))
                targetsToDelete.add(target);
        }

        for (CCSprite target : targetsToDelete)
        {
            _targets.remove(target);
            removeChild(target, true);
        }

        if (targetsToDelete.size() > 0)
            projectilesToDelete.add(projectile);
    }

    for (CCSprite projectile : projectilesToDelete)
    {
        _projectiles.remove(projectile);
        removeChild(projectile, true);

        if (++_projectilesDestroyed > 30)
        {
            _projectilesDestroyed = 0;
            CCDirector.sharedDirector().replaceScene(GameOverLayer.scene("You Win!"));

        CCMenuItemFont item1 = CCMenuItemFont.item("Next level", this, "onNextlevel");
        item1.setColor(new ccColor3B(0,0,0));
        CCMenu menu = CCMenu.menu(item1);
        menu.alignItemsVertically();
        addChild(menu);
    }
    }
    }



      public void onNextlevel()
        {
        try {

            CCScene scene = CCScene.node();
            scene.addChild(new Level1(color1), 0);
            CCDirector.sharedDirector().replaceScene(scene);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       }
```

Logcat error:

`W/System.err(2037): java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onNextlevel [class java.lang.Object]
   W/System.err(2037):  at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
   W/System.err(2037):  at org.cocos2d.menus.CCMenuItem.<init>(CCMenuItem.java:54)
   W/System.err(2037):  at org.cocos2d.menus.CCMenuItemLabel.<init>(CCMenuItemLabel.java:43)
   W/System.err(2037):  at org.cocos2d.menus.CCMenuItemFont.<init>(CCMenuItemFont.java:49)
   W/System.err(2037):  at org.cocos2d.menus.CCMenuItemFont.item(CCMenuItemFont.java:44)
   W/System.err(2037):  at com.tutorials.cocos2dsimplegame.GameLayer.update(GameLayer.java:253)
   W/System.err(2037):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   W/System.err(2037):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:513)
   W/System.err(2037):  at org.cocos2d.actions.CCTimer.update(CCTimer.java:82)
   W/System.err(2037):  at org.cocos2d.actions.CCScheduler.tick(CCScheduler.java:252)
   W/System.err(2037):  at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCDirector.drawCCScene(CCDirector.java:692)
   W/System.err(2037):  at org.cocos2d.nodes.CCDirector.onDrawFrame(CCDirector.java:663)
   W/System.err(2037):  at org.cocos2d.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1171)
   W/System.err(2037):  at org.cocos2d.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1080)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's telling you that the "this" class has no onNextLevel method.

It also makes no sense to add a menu to the scen you're about to replace because you won't be able to interact with it (let alone see it). You probably want the menu on the new scene, right?

Comment: just replaced this CCDirector.sharedDirector().replaceScene(newLayer.scene());
and its going to next scene but before going to next scene i need to display as LEVEL1 when player click on ok then it should go to next scene how can i do this now

Comment: add an intermediate scene with the menu